# Why are location methods defined on the instance and history methods on prototype?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to understand the architectural decision made while defining the placeholder for dom object methods. For example:

location object methods are defined on the same location object not    on the Location.prototype.

While history methods are defined on the History.prototype not on the    history object.

What is the logic here?

```
var h = Object.getPrototypeOf(history);
h.hasOwnProperty('go'); //true
history.hasOwnProperty('assign'); //false


var l = Object.getPrototypeOf(location);
l.hasOwnProperty('assign'); //false
location.hasOwnProperty('assign');  //true
```

Comment: Both are native methods, and there is not really an architectural decision on how they are exposed. It is not specified either.

Comment: In which browser do you test? In Opera, for example, `assign` is a property of the `LocationPrototype`

Comment: @Bergi, tested in chrome

Comment: Host objects are wild animals, they have their own rules ;)

Comment: @Felix I like your statement :)

Comment: I mean, the developers for sure have some reason to implement it this way or the other, but as bergi said, only the interface is defined, not the implementation. You probably get a better answer (or an answer at all) on some Chrome dev mailing list.

Comment: Thanks Felix, i will try to get some info from chrome mailer.